# Is it realistic to continue academic career if a supervisor is a sophist?

Tags: career-path, mathematics

I was writing my bachelor's degree and that went quite bad. The reason was that my supervisor was a sophist, in my opinion. For example, when I wrote in my thesis:

> "Let n be the cardinality of the set"

The professor said the proof was wrong. Then after tens of times of trial and error I changed that sentence to the form

> "let n be the number of elements of the set".

He accepted it. There were tens of times such small mistakes like this and in hyphenation of a word and he just asked me to fix errors in the thesis without pointing where the mistake is.

Is my career in mathematics finished as I couldn't get along with my thesis supervisor?

Comment: Why do you think it would be finished?

Comment: This is just a bachelor's thesis. In the grand scheme of things, it won't play a very large role. Very, very few mathematicians are like this. It's a dying "teaching" form (thankfully). For the most part, mathematicians have shied away from the philosophy side of things and have really cut out the superfluous nonsense like this.

Comment: My response (and I admit I am quite often deliberately irritating to people who annoy me) would be to insert a definition above this, "Definition 1. Let the meaning in this document of 'cardinality of a set' be equivalent in every sense to that imputed by the phrase 'the number of elements in the set' " and I would leave the rest of the document as it stood. :)

Answer (score 13):

Overall I find your question rather strange.  First of all the word "sophist" is rarely used to describe living people; in my experience it mostly refers to a school of teachers of rhetoric in ancient Greece.  I had to look up the dictionary definition to see what I think you mean.  The third definition [here](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/sophist) is

> 3. (loosely, by extension) One who is captious, fallacious, or deceptive in argument.

If it helps:

> captious:
>
> - (obsolete) That captures; especially, (of an argument, words etc.) designed to capture or entrap in misleading arguments; sophistical.
> - Having a disposition to find fault unreasonably or to raise petty objections; cavilling, nitpicky

So it sounds like you think your advisor is finding fault unreasonably and making petty objections.  I have two points in response.

1) In my experience, the majority of the time students think that about their advisors, they are mistaken: the problem is actually one of miscommunication.  I think it is very likely that there are *reasons* for the comments your advisor has made and that you just haven't found them yet.  You wrote

> after tens of times of trial and error

This is a huge red flag of poor communication.  You shouldn't be editing your thesis by "trial and error", and you shouldn't have to edit it "tens of times" to address any one sentence.  When someone tells you that a proof is wrong, you ask them why.  If they don't tell you, you double check it yourself, come back and say "I'm sorry, but I wasn't able to figure out your objection to the argument: it still looks valid to me.  Can we discuss it in detail?"  If the answer is a hard **no**, then more than a sophist, you would be dealing with someone who is not actually advising you.

In this case it is not even clear (to me, anyway) based on what you said that the issue lies with "cardinality" versus "number of elements".  You are not getting specific enough feedback, so how do you know that this was the problem?  That you think it was is in itself worth a followup conversation: the cardinality of a finite set is indeed the number of elements of that set, so why would one be acceptable and the other not?  You should find out.

2) Assuming that your advisor actually is captious, fallacious, deceptive, or is totally unwilling to explain himself: those are all bad things about him.  Why would his bad qualities ruin your career?  I could say more, but I'd need to hear more about why you're concerned.  At the moment this concern is at the level of a *non sequitur* to the rest of your question.

Comment: I think you make good points, but there are some wholly difficult "mathematicians." I've known a few who were a bit tyrannical and obsessed over minor details like the ones OP has mentioned. Undoubtedly you've probably run into a couple yourself. It's far from being common but it happens. :/ I think the reason OP is questioning themself is that this is probably not the first time such confrontation has happened and it's making OP question their worth as a mathematician. (Read: self-esteem issues.)

Comment: @Cameron: Undoubtedly probably.  But obsessed with minor details is one thing.  Being unwilling or unable to explain your obsessions to your advisee is something else: I have never seen that.  And not to sound unsympathetic, but: witnessing strange or pathological behavior of others does not make me question my self worth.  I'm going to need a little more information to really understand the OP's concerns.

Comment: Completely understandable. I haven't met people quite this.. difficult in mathematics (close, but not quite this bad) but I've known the type outside of mathematics. Some people enjoy the ego trip. Hopefully OP can keep it together enough to get through this and enjoy a master's/PhD with an advisor they get along with well.

Comment: It seems unreasonable to fault a question because in this particular instance you had to look up the definition of one of the words. ;)

Comment: @Calchas: Calling the question "strange" is not exactly faulting it: I didn't downvote or vote to close.  And I did know the word "sophist" but I needed help to understand the way the OP used it.  ("Sophistry" usually means slick-sounding but fallacious arguments, especially those that are made to win an argument rather than to get at the truth.  That doesn't square with what the OP describes.)  The combination of this unusually used word with the lack of logical connection between the flaws of the advisor and the OP's career makes the question asked in the title...rather strange.

Answer (score 1):

> Is my career in mathematics finished as I couldn't get along with my thesis supervisor?

**If your account of the story is accurate**, your advisor is either evil or a didactical failure. I would rather say that if you actually got along with this style of advising, this would count against you. So, this does not say anything against you and unless you want to specialise a particular subfield of mathematics that you can only pursue under this supervisor (which is very unlikely), your career is not finished. Choose a better advisor for your next thesis and that is it. The only drawback you suffer from is probably the sup-par grade of your bachelor thesis and not having the experience of writing a thesis under regular conditions.

As a sidenote: If your account is accurate, I would consider this a denial of supervision and thus inappropriate behaviour. You should take this issue to your faculty’s student body (or similar) as well as to appropriate people from the faculty (e.g., a professor responsible for student issues). This may not have any positive effect on you, but at least you can spare other students your fate.

However, you should also **check whether you are at least part of the problem**: If a supervisor acts as you described to everybody, it’s unlikely that you did not encounter any big red warning signs before choosing him or at least after starting your thesis work:

- News of such bad supervising should spread quickly amongst other students.
- The supervisor’s workgroup should be comparably small.
- Other members of the workgroup are likely to have informed you about this behaviour.

Did you in any way communicate with your supervisor about these issues, such as asking him to explain your errors to you? In particular, consider that your supervisor may not have realised that he told you ten times that something is wrong and just thought that at each instance he was pointing out a new error or an error he had missed before – which would likely not render the advising good, but at least it would not be abysmal anymore.

Comment: Before escalating, the OP should talk with him and explain how the method is not working. If things don't change, then, escalate.

Comment: @Davidmh: Right, though if the asker did not already talk with the supervisor about this, we very likely have a case where the asker is part of the problem.